# Are there any Outlook-compatable exchange alternatives?

Tags: exchange, blackberry, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office

I'm searching for a outlook-compatable solution for my company ... I've found codeTwo company, with there software: http://www.codetwo.com/public-folders/ , for syncing calender ..

Its great product, but if someone has a better solution / idea  ( better software for lower price) or something like that it would be great.

It need to work with blackberry, outlook 2007, outlook 2003... outlook express ..

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered looking at [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/products/compare_products.html)? I haven't tried it personally, but it looks like it can support the features you are looking for (depending on the edition).

Comment: We use Zimbra 5.0.x with about 70 Blackberry devices connected through BES.  The 6.0 branch has better BES support and even BES Express now, so I would recommend going for that.There is also a ZCO (Zimbra Connector for Outlook) that will work with Outlook clients and have the same user experience as if they were connected to exchange.  As far as outlook express, ZCO doesn't support that, but you can still connect to it as an IMAP client.

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted is an extension to Outlook that will allow sharing of calendar and contact data across a local network WITHOUT Microsoft Exchange Server.

How many users do you have?

If you have a relatively small number, consider a hosted Exchange solution. If you have a large number (say, >50, depending on the prices) you need to seriously consider running your own Exchange server ($$$) with BES Express (free) to handle BlackBerries.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Rackspace's Hosted Exchange](http://www.rackspace.com/apps/email_hosting/exchange_hosting/) service at my office. I believe it is about $10/user/month.

It works well and has all the features that you'd expect from Exchange but you don't manage anything. We have Outlook 2003, 2007, and 2010 clients. I have also configured iPods via IMAP/SMTP, so I believe it would work just fine with Outlook Express.

BlackBerry Enterprise Server can be enabled on an individual user basis for an additional $10/phone/month. Calendar/Contact sharing works properly.

ActiveSync for iPhones, Android, and Windows mobile is $3/phone/month.

There is also a "Hybrid Exchange" setup where not all of your accounts need to be actual Exchange users. We do not use this, but it looks interesting.

Data Point: We have 20 users on this system with 1 BlackBerry. Everyone is happy, especially me, since now I don't have to manage an Exchange Server :)